# Why I can define a function that differs in the top-level constness of some of its paramters?

Tags: c++, function

Usually functions and classes are declared in header files and defined in some source files for example I have this function which just takes a constant reference to an int and returns bool value deciding whether the parameter is even or odd:

So in my header `odd_even.h` I have written:

```
    bool is_even(const int& x); // I used const ref. to avoid copy and unintentional modification of the argument.
```

And in the source `odd_even.cpp`:

```
bool is_even(int& x) { 
    if (x = 1024) // some unintentional assinemnt (==) though modern compilers detect it.
        ; //some statement here
    //x = 1024; // or here another unintentional modification
    return !(x % 2) ? true : false; 
}
```

And the driver program:

```
int main(){

    int a{ 17 };
    std::cout << (a) << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_even(a) << endl;

    std::cout << (a) << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

As you can see the function `is_even` definition modifies the argument unintentionally and the client of my program doesn't realize that this function will modify the argument as long as its declaration which takes a const reference to int.

So is there a workaround about this mistake which prevents such mistake?

Comment: Don't pass a reference. Pass by value: `bool is_even(int x)`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: What about a big container where I should pass by reference?

Comment: This should result in a linker error. What compiler/linker are you using?

Comment: This compiles? C++ allows const parameter overload when using a pointer or a reference

Comment: @juanchopanza: MSVC++ 14. I don't think so as the fact that top-level const is dropped from parameters.

Comment: This example shouldn't compile. You define a different function than declared, so linker will return something like `undefined reference to 'is_even(int const&)'`

Comment: @Syfu_H Your parameters don't have top-level const.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: No. it compiles and runs correctly because it is invoking `is_even(int&)` not `is_even(const int&)`.

Comment: @Alex24 I might be missing something obvious, but it doesn't work in GCC: https://wandbox.org/permlink/nBjjRN4GeGxisbkH . Declared function requires a definition, whether it is used or not.

Comment: @Alex24 Or actually, it depends on the setup and connections between files, as noted in the comments under Raindrop7's answer. [mcve] would be needed to know which one is actually correct.

Answer (score 2):

This should not compile as demonstrated [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25df76e71a4912b5)

C++ allows overload by cv qualifiers when parameter is pointer or reference type, thus it is part of the mangled name.

Answer (score -1):

There is no `top-level const` here:

```
bool is_even(const int& x); // 1
bool is_even(int& x); // 2
```

Above 1 and 2 are totally different signatures: 1 is a function that takes a constant reference to int. Remember the `const` here is `low-level` not `top-level` Also remeber that references don't have top-level const as the fact that they are already constant.

In your example it compiles and runs OK because you are passing a non-const object which is relevant for the signature 2. However if you pass an r-value or then it will fail to link. e.g:

```
std::cout << is_even(77) << std::endl; // link will fail because the 1 is not defined.
```

Comment: OP's example should compile but not link because the definition for `bool is_even(const int& x);` is missing.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel: The program links correctly it is invoking `is_even(int&)` not `is_even(const int&)`. But this won't link: `is_even(63)` becuase here `63` is a literal so it invokes `is_even(const int&)` which is not defined.

Comment: There is no declaration for `is_even(int&)` in the header, so there is no way the compiler could attempt to call this function in `main`. At least if we are to assume that the declarations from that header are the only declarations the compiler gets to see when compiling `main`, which is what the question would seem to imply…

Comment: I think we need to ask for a MCVE (MVCE?).  My assumption was that `main.cpp` includes only `odd_even.h` and therefore doesn't have any declaration of the `bool is_even(int& x)` overload to factor into overload resolution - so it resolves to `bool is_even(const int& x)` which is never defined anywhere.